# Highcharts / highstock how to change title of chart in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, highcharts

I want to change chart title dynamically. Using browsers different than IE it's simply as:

```
$('.highcharts-title>tspan','#container').text('some text');
```

How to do this in IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works in all browsers:

```
$('.highcharts-title','#container').text('some text');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've the chart object then you can use the method setTitle, for details see http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#chart-object.

Otherwise you'll need a different selector for IE as you don't need the child tspan as the title is just a span. (This was with IE8, other version may render it differently).

Comment: Your answer is useful, but i'm not sure if it works with highstock. Anyway I found solution.